# How to modify the locally defined variable in the it block when modifying it in the cascaded promises

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, protractor

I want to access/modify the locally defined variable of the it block inside the cascaded multiple promises

Something like this

```
describe('make the app to fail',function(){
  it('should have error', function(){
    var canYouModifyMe = 0;
    anArrayofAlertElements.count().then(function(total){
      anArrayofAlertElements.get(0).isDisplayed().then(function(value){
        canYouModifyMe = 'yes'; // proven that it goes here
      });
    });
    console.log(canYouModifyMe); // Here's the problem, this is still 0. Im expecting it to be "yes"
  });
})
```

I already moved the variable in the onPrepare function (to make it globally accessible, but doesnt work)
How can i modify a locally defined variable in the it block in cascaded promise?

Just in case you want more detailed code, check the below code.

```
// html file
// different errors
<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="data.error" >
{{(data.message)}}
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="cart.error" >
{{cart.message}} 
</div>
...
- some other error goes here -


// page object 
function Util() {
  this.getAlertMessages = function(){
    return element.all(by.css('.alert'));
  }

  this.expectAlertMessages = function(){
    var that = this;
    var errorCount = 0; 
    this.getAlertMessages().count().then(function(count){          
      for(i=0;i<count;i++){    
that.getAlertMessages().get(i).isDisplayed().then(function(data){
          // for debugging purposes, lets make it always true so it increments error count
          data = true;           
          if (data===true) {
            errorCount++; // here is the problem. it doesnt increment the above defined variable "errorCount"
          }             
        });
      }
      return errorCount; // this is still 0
    }).then(function(obj){
      // errorCount still 0, that is supposedly 1
      expect(errorCount).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
  }
}
```

In summary, i just want to test if there's any alert messages displayed.

Im stuck on this, hoping that someone here can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that we are talking about `promises` and `async` execution.

Definitely, by the time that you print the value of `canYouModifyMe` the `callback` from the `promise` in which you modify the value was not executed. Try below code to see that the execution order is different:

```
describe('make the app to fail',function(){
  it('should have error', function(done){
    var canYouModifyMe = 0;
    anArrayofAlertElements.count().then(function(total){
      anArrayofAlertElements.get(0).isDisplayed().then(function(value){
        canYouModifyMe = 'yes'; // proven that it goes here
        console.log('Inside callback. Current value is', canYouModifyMe);
        done();
      });
    });
    console.log('Current value is', canYouModifyMe); // Here's the problem, this is still 0. Im expecting it to be "yes"
  });
})
```

Also, you should have noticed the usage of another `done` callback in above code. That is another detail about `async` execution and `jasmine`. Basically by running that callback, we tell the `test` (`spec`) That the execution for it has finished.

Comment: Still doesnt change the canYouModifyMe.  I want to change that variable to stop looping if element.isDisplayed()==true, then triggers the test to be success. if the loop ends and still element.isDisplayed()==false, then definitely theres no error alert found, it should trigger that the test failed. In summary, what i want to do is if there is at least 1 alert message, test is success, if there is no alert message is found, test is failed.

Comment: This code should not fix your issue as you did not provide all the code. BUT, it should let you understand what is really happening there. Applying this code provided, what do you get in console?